# Check If an Item by same title exists in sharepoint list then display that info in the Infopath form

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, list, infopath, infopath-rules

I have a requirement like this.

I have a SharePoint list named 'Examdate' which stores different CoursNumber, Semester and ExamDate. It uses an InfoPath form for entering the CoursNumber in the list.

Now they need to have a mechanism to find out if the user is adding a New ExamDate whose CoursNumber is already present. They don't want the users to stop the adding process, but instead, want to display the ExamDate for this already existing CoursNumber in the form. This should not happen on the save button.

So, I was thinking of customizing the `NewItem` form by adding a button near the CoursNumber field, say "Check Existence",   and check if the CoursNumber and Semester exists by that number entered by the user. But I dont know how I can implement this.

What’s the best and simplest way I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

1st- You need to add a new connection to the list and select the fields you want to query.

Then on the "Check existence" you'll add a couple of Action rules

1. Query Data connection
2. Set field value

   you'll have to filter the data extracted from your connection and check if there are more results than cero,

   for this you'll use a conditional operator :

   > (condition operator value), example ( results > 0 )

you'll have to filter the data on the formula builder by clicking "insert Field or Group" and you'll have to switch to the advanced view, there you will change the connection (top dropdown) to the connection you created, you will expand data fields and select the field you want to query, and you will click "filter Data" on the left-down corner.

Then you will select the field you are filtering on the left side of the condition, on the right side you will select a field and you'll switch to the main connection and then select the field you are using as a filter.

the formula should look something like this :

> (count(Title[. = Title]) > 0)  -- this should return true or false